# Is there a way to use a game loop or Refresh a Linear Layout within a different class?

Tags: android, layout, view

My app i'm currently developing needs to refresh a Linear Layout that i'm dynamically adding Views too. I currently am adding all of the Views within the UI thread but have a separate Dialog class which upon a button click within the Dialog will need to refresh/Re draw the Linear Layout. Is there a way I can refresh the Linear Layout within a different class (trying to stay very object oriented in my program design) or a way to use a game loop for a Linear Layout to refresh the View every 3 seconds? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you don't need to manually "redraw" anything. As soon as you change the contents of your layout (and as soon as android can get around to it (which will be a LOT faster than 3 seconds)) you'll see the updated screen.  As to what thread you do this from, you can only change your layouts from the main thread, as far as I know, but you can call Runnable methods in that thread via a handler from anywhere.

Comment: Ah ok so if I can postInvalidate for a runnable method it should handle it. agreed but some changes to Views like layout properties requires the screen to be manually reDrawn because android will not refresh upon a layout change from what i've tried